# How to call app_path() function in laravel lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, html-email, lumen

How to call app_path() function or to make a Helper for app_path() function in Laravel lumen?
I need it because i got this error,.. "Call to undefined function app_path()"
It has a package here for that,.. but is not supported for Laravel Lumen version 7
Anyone knows hot to make it?

[image]

thanks,.. sorry for my english,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the error now,.
i added this to my `app/Helpers/helpers.php` file.

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('app_path')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to the application folder.
     *
     * @param  string $path
     * @return string
     */
    function app_path($path = '')
    {
        return app('path') . ($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $path : $path);
    }
}
```

for the other config.
dont forget to add this in `composer.json`
file:

```
"autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

and run this command: `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `app()->basePath('app')`